# Hopf bifurcation computation fail

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

For few days I am working on Hopf bifurcation of a system like this:

$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=\alpha\frac{x^2 y + a x y}{x^2+bx+1}-1\\
\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{1-y-cx^2 y }{1+x^2}
$$

above $\alpha$ is the bifurcation parameter and $a,\;b,\;c$ are real parameters.  I want to determine the parameter value that the Hopf bifurcation would occur. I have 2 sources (a thesis and an article focusing on another set of equations) for finding the parameters, I tried to recreate their results but I failed miserably.  Found steady state values as $x=x(\alpha),\;y=y(x)$

$$
0=\alpha\frac{x^2 y + a x y}{x^2+bx+1}-1\\
0=\frac{1-y-cx^2 y }{1+x^2}\\
$$
then for combining two equations from y
$$
y=\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{x^2+bx+1}{x^2  + a x }\\
y=\frac{1}{1+cx^2}
$$

and got an equation for $x$ and $\alpha$ only

$$
{\alpha}=\frac{(1+cx^2)(x^2+bx+1)}{x^2  + a x }
$$

now stated bifurcation parameter in terms of the stated state. Then for

$$
F(x,y)=\alpha\frac{x^2 y + a x y}{x^2+bx+1}-1\\
G(x,y)=\frac{1-y-cx^2 y }{1+x^2}
$$

wrote the characteristic equation and solve for lambda to find eigenvalues of the system. Meanwhile replaced

$$
y\to\frac{1}{1+cx^2}\\
{\alpha}\to\frac{(1+cx^2)(x^2+bx+1)}{x^2  + a x }
$$
at the characteristic equation solution.
For finding Hopf bifurcation I look for the the values of $x$ making the eigenvalue of the Jacobian $0$, such that by replacing those $x$ values can find the exact Hopf b. value from
$$
{\alpha}=\frac{(1+cx^2)(x^2+bx+1)}{x^2  + a x }
$$
however it does give wrong answers. Can you trace something wrong here? (Let's say everything looks good can you please suggest a document where each step in the computation is clear so that I can go through and realize where i do wrong)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to find the stationary point(s) in terms of **only** the parameters. That is, the equation ${\alpha}=\frac{(1+cx^2)(x^2+bx+1)}{x^2  + a x }$ must still be solved for $x$.

Comment: @HansEngler appearently both sources uses a variable with a different value. My problem is solved. Thank you for your response. I will delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the variable $x$ complicates the equilibrium calculation, so we set $x=x_0$ and $y=y_0$, and solve as follows for $\alpha$ and $c$:

$$
(\alpha^*,c^*)=\left(\frac{b x_0+x_0^2+1}{x_0 y_0 \left(a+x_0\right)},\frac{1-y_0}{x_0^2 y_0} \right)
$$

In this way, by setting $\alpha=\alpha^*$ and $c=c^*$, your equilibrium point is given by $(x_0,y_0)$. Now, for example, if we consider that $x_0=\frac{1}{2}$ and $y_0=\frac{1}{2}$, and considering $a=1$ and $b=1$, we obtain two non-trivial equilibria, as shown in the following figure:

[image]

On the other hand, the linear approximation at $(1/2,1/2)$ is given by

$$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{4 (3 a+b+4)}{(2 a+1) (2 b+5)} & 2 \\
 -\frac{8}{5} & -\frac{8}{5} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Considering $b$ as bifurcation parameter, we have that the critical Hopf bifurcation value is given by

$$
b_0=\frac{5 (2-a)}{8 a-1}\hspace{0.5cm}\text{and}\hspace{0.5cm}\text{det}(A(a,b_0))=\frac{16}{25}>0.
$$

The transversality condition:

$$
\frac{d}{db}(-\text{tr}(A(a,b_0))=\frac{4 (1-8 a)^2}{75 (2 a+1)^2}>0.
$$

Therefore, the equilibrium point $(1/2,1/2)$ is locally asymptotically stable for $b<b_0$ and exhibits a Hopf bifurcation when $b\geq b_0$. You can verify that the eigenvalues at critical bifurcation value are purely imaginary and are the following:

$$
\lambda=\frac{4}{5}i\hspace{0.5cm}\text{and}\hspace{0.5cm}\bar{\lambda}=-\frac{4}{5}i
$$

The limit cycle considering $a=1$ and $b=b_0+1/10000$:

[image]

Only the calculation of the first Lyapunov coefficient is needed to have a complete proof of the existence of the Hopf bifurcation.

If you want a more complete proof, don't assign numerical values to $x_0$ and $y_0$ and proceed in the same way. You just have to take care that the determinant of the linear approximation at the critical bifurcation value is strictly positive.